# How to edit database table in JSF

Tags: jsf, jdbc, datatable, jsf-2

I'm having a bean class with id,firstName,lastName attributes having public getters and setters, and an updateEmployee method.

i'm using following jsf page to get database table values.

When i click on update button success page is shown but values are not changing in the database. Can any one tell me the reason that why vales are not getting change in the database?

Thanks in advance.

**JSF page:**

```
<h:dataTable value="#{tableBean.employeeList}" var="employee" border="1">
   <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">First name</f:facet>
          <h:inputText value="#{employee.firstName}" />
   </h:column>

   <h:column>
          <f:facet name="header">Last name</f:facet>
          <h:inputText value="#{employee.lastName}" />
   </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value = "update" action="#{employee.updateEmployee}"/>
```

Employee.java:

```
public String updateEmployee(){
   String query = "update employee set firstName = ?,lastName = ? where id = 1";         
   pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   pstmt.setString(2,this.firstName);
   pstmt.setString(3,this.lastName); 
   pstmt.executeUpdate(); // execute update statement
   conn.commit();
   committed = true;
   return "success.xhtml";
   }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return null;
   } finally {
      try{
         if (!committed) conn.rollback();
              pstmt.close();
          conn.close();
       }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your catch / finally block looks quite strange. I hope this is no production code. It would be interesting to know what happes at `System.exit(1)` with your web application ... Will the server exit ? ;-) ..... Just tested: Yes, server down.

Comment: This is a DB/JDBC problem. Please uncouple JSF logic from data access logic. Create a standalone Java program with `main()` method where you do the pure JDBC task and provide that as the problem code snippet instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your values are automatically bound if you have the corresponding properties in your backing bean.

You have to submit your data in order to get bean values updated. Add a commandButton or commandLink in your form like this:

```
<h:form>
 <h:dataTable> ... </h:dataTable>
 <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="tableBean.actionMethod">
</h:form>
```

Comment: @Handy: Thanks for reply, i've edited the question, please check again.

Comment: I strongly recommend to start using a debugger. Set a breakpoint on the first line of your `updateEmployee` method and go further stepwise. Check the state of all variables after each step. There are some suspicious parts in your code, e.g. your form contains an input field id and your query has id set to "1".

Answer (score 1):

You have only two parameter placeholders in the query, but you refer to 2nd and 3rd parameters later:

```
pstmt.setString(2,this.firstName);
pstmt.setString(3,this.lastName);
```